# Cannot choose related Lead in email alert salesforce

Tags: process-builder, email-template, email-alert, email2lead

I have a custom object called 'Interview' which has a Lookup relationship with Lead. When an interview is arranged, I want the process builder to send an auto email to the lead. Unfortunately, there is no option available to choose the related Lead in the email alert. I can choose Lead owner and related contact but there is no option for the lead email address.

Comment: delegate the work to a Lightning Flow

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't have any experience with Flow. Does that use the same email alert as process builder?

Answer (score 1):

The basic workaround would be to add a workflow rule that sets a new background field called "Related Lead Email".  The email field can then be selected for use by the email alert.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you mean by background field? Are talking about creating a formula field on the interview (child) object to fetch lead (parent object) email address?

Comment: I have already created a formula field on the interview object with return type of 'text' (because I cannot choose email as return type) but I am still not able to use this field as the recipient in email alert.

Comment: It can't be a formula field.  It must be an empty email field that is populated by a workflow when the related lead is set.  The email alert function has a hard requirement for an email-type, not formula, field.